# How to filter data out, when using GROUP in SQL

Tags: sql

I got this SQL-statement:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM    accelerator_clinic_patient_status 
      ORDER BY status_id DESC) t 
INNER JOIN accelerator_clinic_campaign_patient_signup signup 
ON    (signup.patient_id = t.patient_id)
INNER JOIN accelerator_clinic_campaign campaign 
ON    (signup.campaign_id = campaign.campaign_id 
       AND campaign.clinic_user_id = 4978)
GROUP BY t.patient_id
```

The code finds out the latest status in the table "accelerator_clinic_patient_status"

It contains columns patient_id which is a foregin-key, each patient_id can contain multiple status's.

[image: data example here]

But what I am interested in, is getting a list of patient id whose LATEST status is "Booked" -- I want to filter out Not Booked in the list, when doing the select-statement (for example in the posted image, the data should not be shown in the query, because the latest status is Not Booked). The code right now returns a list with the latest status.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What is your RDBMS? You are using a `group by` without aggregation, it's best practice to use `distinct` instead.

Comment: Do a Row_Number() over (partiton by Patient_Id order by date_added desc) and add where Status = "Booked" and Row_Number = 1

Answer (score 0):

Try This,
Please Improve the following code syntactically,

```
select *,Rank() over (partiton by X.Patient_Id order by X.date_added desc) as Rankk from (SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM    accelerator_clinic_patient_status 
      ORDER BY status_id DESC) t 
INNER JOIN accelerator_clinic_campaign_patient_signup signup 
ON    (signup.patient_id = t.patient_id)
INNER JOIN accelerator_clinic_campaign campaign 
ON    (signup.campaign_id = campaign.campaign_id 
       AND campaign.clinic_user_id = 4978)
GROUP BY t.patient_id) as X where Rankk=1 and Status = 'Booked'
```

In Mysql ,Something like this,

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1,* 
          FROM    (accelerator_clinic_patient_status 
          ORDER BY status_id DESC) t 
    INNER JOIN accelerator_clinic_campaign_patient_signup signup 
    ON    (signup.patient_id = t.patient_id)
    INNER JOIN accelerator_clinic_campaign campaign 
    ON    (signup.campaign_id = campaign.campaign_id 
           AND campaign.clinic_user_id = 4978)
    GROUP BY t.patient_id) X 
Group By Patient_Id Order By date_added Desc
```

Comment: it gives the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partiton by X.Patient_Id order by X.date_added desc) as Rankk from (SELECT t.*
' at line 1

Comment: Hi @MartinAndersen I see that you are using Mysql,My Solution was to SQL-Server,Let me see how to mimic Rank Functiion in Mysql

Comment: @MartinAndersen i am trying to Learn a bit of MySql trying to solve the problem with you,You can Visit http://www.fromdual.com/ranking-mysql-results and http://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/grouped-rank-function-mysql-sql-query.html

Comment: See if the current query returning us a the required answer ,If yes ,we will filter it out.